# TensorFlow Lite 2.0 advanced GPU using on Android with C++

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow2.0

I am new in TensorFlow. I built TensorFlow Lite libraries from sources. I try to use TensorFlow for face recognition. This one a part of my project. And I have to use GPU memory for input/output e.g. input data: opengl texture, output data: opengl texture. Unfortunately, this information is outdated: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced. I tried to use gpu::gl::InferenceBuilder for building gpu::gl::InferenceRunner. And I have problem. I don’t understand how I can get the model in GraphFloat32 (Model>) format and TfLiteContext.

Example of my experemental code:

```
using namespace tflite::gpu;
using namespace tflite::gpu::gl;

const TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2 options = {
        .inference_preference = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PREFERENCE_SUSTAINED_SPEED,
        .is_precision_loss_allowed = 1 // FP16
};

tfGPUDelegate = TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Create(&options);
if (interpreter->ModifyGraphWithDelegate(tfGPUDelegate) != kTfLiteOk) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tensorflow", "GPU Delegate hasn't been created");
    return ;
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Tensorflow", "GPU Delegate has been created");
}

InferenceEnvironmentOptions envOption;
InferenceEnvironmentProperties properties;
auto envStatus = NewInferenceEnvironment(envOption, &env, &properties);

if (envStatus.ok()){
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Tensorflow", "Inference environment has been created");
 } else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tensorflow", "Inference environment hasn't been created");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tensorflow", "Message: %s", envStatus.error_message().c_str());
}

InferenceOptions builderOptions;
builderOptions.usage = InferenceUsage::SUSTAINED_SPEED;
builderOptions.priority1 = InferencePriority::MIN_LATENCY;
builderOptions.priority2 = InferencePriority::AUTO;
builderOptions.priority3 = InferencePriority::AUTO;

//The last part requires a model
//   GraphFloat32* graph;
//   TfLiteContext* tfLiteContex;
//
//   auto buildStatus = BuildModel(tfLiteContex, delegate_params, &graph);
//   if (buildStatus.ok()){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look function BuildFromFlatBuffer (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6458d346470158605ecb5c5ba6ad390ae0dc6014/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/common/testing/tflite_model_reader.cc). It creates Interpreter and graph from it.

Also Mediapipe uses InferenceRunner you may find for useful in files:
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/calculators/tflite/tflite_inference_calculator.cc
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/ecb5b5f44ab23ea620ef97a479407c699e424aa7/mediapipe/util/tflite/tflite_gpu_runner.cc